# SQL show only the top 2 comments for each actionid

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the top n rows within a group by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004079/selecting-the-top-n-rows-within-a-group-by-clause)

I have the following data:

```
id actionid commentid 
1  1        1 
2  1        2
3  1        3
4  2        1
```

I want to create a sql to only show the top 2 comments for each actionid.  In that case I the sql should only return id (1,2,4)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       actionid, 
       commentid
FROM (
   SELECT id, 
          actionid, 
          commentid, 
          row_number() over (partition by actionid order by id) rn
   FROM your_table
) t
WHERE rn <= 2
```